# Commenting the source code from an XML file

Tags: c++, xml-documentation

Normally the documentation comments are used to generate an XML documentation file. I looking for the opposite, a utility that could take input from an XML file and place the source documentation tags in the source file.

Is there anything relevant to this?

Comment: Interesting idea. However, this counts as off-topic for requesting off-site resources.

Comment: I could ask "how can I achieve this" ... and somebody (hopefully) would say "look for this" ... that would be also off-site :-)

Comment: That would be "too broad" :)